# Continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$ determined by different limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

The function $f$ is defined as

$$f(x, y) =\frac{x^2 y^2} {x^2 y^2 +|x-y|}$$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $0$ otherwise.

We can clearly take two different paths $y=x$ and $y=-x$ which would give two different limits and thus $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.  How would introducing polar coordinates lead to such a result exactly?

Comment: Don't forget to put $ before and after a MathJax expression.

Comment: This isn't in any way relevant or important, but using the word "otherwise" there seems strange to me.

Comment: Compare $\theta=\frac\pi4$ and $\theta=\frac{3\pi}4$.

Comment: My problem began when I tried to add and subtract |x-y| and separate the fraction then introducing polar coordinates and the limit became 0. So how is it possible to prove the discontinuity using polar coordinates?

Comment: $\theta=\frac\pi4$ gives $x=y$ and $\theta=\frac{3\pi}4$ gives $x=-y$.